# How to convert a locally stored image to base64?

Tags: javascript, image, base64

I have an image path which it is stored locally.
For example,

```
let path = 'C:\Users\Jonnie\Desktop'
```

How do I get the image by using JavaScript only and convert it to base64?

Comment: Is this JavaScript part of a node app ? A web app ?

Comment: @Titus it is at the client-side of a web app

Comment: In that case, you cannot access the file directly, the user will have to give the web app access to it. You can use a `<input type="file"/>` for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
function imageToBase64(img)
{
    var canvas, ctx, dataURL, base64;
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    base64 = dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "");
    return base64;
}
```

[source](https://gist.github.com/gfcarvalho/9502621)

Now you just need to pass your image to there

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<canvas>` for this.

Create a canvas and load in the image then use `toDataURL()` to get it in `base64`

The documentation for `<canvas>` can be found  [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement)